# Are some JavaFX layouts not compatible with Mac computers?

Tags: java, layout, javafx, scenebuilder

Ran into this problem a couple of times over building this application and is now really impeding our functionality. The problem first started when my other developer (using a mac) tried to run our application when I changed a line of code affecting the stage:

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        overallStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        overallStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        overallStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        overallStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

This was to allow maximising of the screen after the user logs in. After the mac user logs in, the stage would instead minimise into a tiny window in the bottom left corner then disappear. A similar thing is now occurring with a new addition I made.

[image]

I made this addition to incorporate a side menu within the application. As you can see, I wrapped the whole scene in a Stack Pane and then Anchor pane (see hierarchy) with an external anchor pane for the side-menu. Now the exact same thing is occurring where it would minimise and disappear on two different Macs, Windows is perfectly fine.

Something is leading me to believe that some layouts and stage settings are not compatible with Macs as it only occurred again after I wrapped the main scene, has anyone experienced this issue or know how to fix it?

Comment: Really good question!

Comment: The actual layout code is written in Java, so it should do the same thing on any system (at least if the systems are running the same JDK version). The `Screen` API (`Screen.getPrimary()` and `screen.getVisualBounds()`) must obviously communicate with the native system and potentially do some coordinate transformations. Can you log what values you are getting for the screen bounds on the different systems? Which JDK version is each system running? Some earlier JDK versions on Mac had bugs transforming native screen coordinates into the coordinate system used by JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting stage values, you should:

```
    //Initialize Group root for Main Node
    Group root = new Group();

    //Initialize Scene on group root with specific sizes
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);

    //Initialize BorderPane and Bind the layout with the scene size.
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

    //Set the TabPane to be centered
    borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);

    //Adds Layout to Main Node
    root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
```

This would automatically change the window size depending on the resolution of your screen along side all of your controls. Thus, allowing you to make your JavaFX compatible with all operating systems.

GoodLuck. Let me know if you would like any further help. :)